# How to cut Mp3 file from android code

Tags: android

I am making a phone call recording app and I want to cut the noise of caller tone from recording.

I want to know that, is there a way to cut an mp3 file by code?

Comment: https://github.com/google/ringdroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically with pure Android SDK, it is not possible.  but u can use this library [Ringdroid](https://github.com/google/ringdroid) open source project. or use this [github](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/)